# xsd - How to get some elements as choice

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have below xml,

```
<miniHome>
    <required>
        <washing_machine/>
        <vessels/>
        <refrigerator/><!--THIS SHOULD BE A CHOICE-->
        <cooler/><!--THIS SHOULD BE A CHOICE-->
    </required>
</miniHome>
```

In this i need to make 'refrigerator' and 'cooler' as choice. Only one should be present at a time. And these two elements are not mandatory.

The problem here is that i need to fit this requirement in below xsd

```
<xs:complexType name="homeOperationType"/>
<xs:element name="homeType" type="homeOperationType" abstract="true"/>

<xs:complexType name="miniHomeType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="homeOperationType">
                <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="AC"/>
                    <xs:element name="washing_machine"/>
                    <xs:element ref="cooler"/> <!--THIS SHOULD BE A CHOICE-->
                    <xs:element ref="refridgerator"/> <!--THIS SHOULD BE A CHOICE-->
                </xs:choice>
                </xs:all>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="miniHome" type="miniHomeType" substitutionGroup="homeType"/>
```

```
<xs:complexType name="coolerType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:anyType"/>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="cooler" type="coolerType"/>

<xs:complexType name="configUriType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:anyURI"/>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="refrigerator" type="configUriType"/>
```

1. The 'cooler' and 'refrigerator' are of above types.
2. 'cooler' and 'refrigerator' are already defined as above and used somewhere else.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can realize the `xs:choice` in an `xs:all` with a `substitutionGroup`. I also had to add a rule for the `required` parent element. This is what came out in total:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="homeOperationType" />
    <xs:element name="homeType" type="homeOperationType" abstract="true"/>

    <xs:complexType name="miniHomeType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="homeOperationType">
                <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="AC" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="washing_machine"/>
                    <xs:element name="vessels"/>
                    <xs:element ref="coolingType" />
                </xs:all>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="coolerType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:anyType"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="configUriType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:anyURI"/>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="coolingType" />   <!--THIS SHOULD BE A CHOICE-->
    <xs:element name="cooler"       type="coolerType" substitutionGroup="coolingType"/>
    <xs:element name="refrigerator" type="configUriType" substitutionGroup="coolingType" />

    <xs:complexType name="miniRequiredType" >
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="required" type="miniHomeType" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="miniHome" type="miniRequiredType" />
</xs:schema>
```

The `substitutionGroup="homeType"` is lost on this example due to the handling of the `required` element, but you surely can reintegrate it into your code.

EDIT: Incorporated additional type definitions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is the exact answer for the question which i posted. When i compare with actual requirement i could see that,

Comment: 1. The 'cooler' is of type 
    <xs:complexType name="coolerType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:anyType"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="cooler" type="coolerType"/>

Comment: and the 'refrigerator' is of type
    <xs:complexType name="configUriType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:anyURI"/>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="refrigerator" type="configUriType"/>

Comment: 2. 'cooler' and 'refrigerator' are alreade defined
 <xs:element name="refrigerator" type="configUriType"/>
    <xs:element name="cooler" type="coolerType"/>